# Notifications in android by comparing the system time with database values using background service is not working properly

Tags: android

I am developing an android app.I wan to provide five notifications per day.I will store the notification time in sqlite database.Then I compare this db notification time with the devices time in a repeating loop using service.But the notification will not work properly.Forceclose appeared.I have given the two class files Third,java and MyService below.......I need the help

```
     Third.java

   public class third extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btnopen;
Spinner spin1,spin2,spin3,spin4,spin5;
EditText t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
String fajr,zuhr,asr,magrib,isha;
String[] item={"","2-Times Allahu akbar","3-Beep once"};
example r=new example();
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYPRAYER.db";   
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notification";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+DATABASE_TABLE+"(id integer primary key autoincrement , fajr varchar not null , zuhr varchar not null , asr varchar not null , magrib varchar not null , isha varchar not null );"; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.page3);
   /* Call the service */
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName( "org.prayer.test","org.prayer.test.MyService" );
    bindService( i, null, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    this.startService(i); 
    /*  Populate the spinner */
btnopen=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
t5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
spin1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spin2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
spin3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
spin4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
spin5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
ArrayAdapter<String> a1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,item);
a1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spin1.setAdapter(a1);
spin2.setAdapter(a1);
spin3.setAdapter(a1);
spin4.setAdapter(a1);
spin5.setAdapter(a1);

         /* Notification time stored on the database */
try
{
        SQLiteDatabase myDB;
        //myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/org.prayer.test/databases/MYPRAYER.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        //myDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        myDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        ContentValues newRow = new ContentValues();
        newRow.put("id", "1");
        newRow.put("fajr", "0:00 AM");
        newRow.put("zuhr", "0:00 AM");
        newRow.put("asr", "0:00 AM");
        newRow.put("magrib", "0:00 AM");
        newRow.put("isha", "0:00 AM");
        myDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newRow);
        myDB.close();
}
catch(SQLiteException ex)
{
    //Do nothing
    //System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

btnopen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         fajr=t1.getText().toString();
         zuhr=t2.getText().toString();
         asr=t3.getText().toString();
         magrib=t4.getText().toString();
         isha=t5.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase myDB;
        myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        ContentValues newRow = new ContentValues();
        newRow.put("id", "1");
        newRow.put("fajr", fajr);
        newRow.put("zuhr", zuhr);
        newRow.put("asr", asr);
        newRow.put("magrib", magrib);
        newRow.put("isha", isha);
        myDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newRow,"id" + "=" + "1",null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "row updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myDB.close();
  }

});
```

}
}

```
MyService.java

ppublic class MyService extends Service {
              private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYPRAYER.db";   
              private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notification";
              String tag="TestService";
                String a="hello";
                String res1,res2,res3,res4,res5;
                int hour,minute;
                String day3,day4,minute1,hour1;
                MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
                   /* Service creation */
               @Override
               public void onCreate() {
             super.onCreate();
               Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
               Log.i(tag, "Service created...");


                  /* Rereive notification times from the databse notificaion */
              SQLiteDatabase myDB;
            myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            String[] resultColumns = new String[] {"fajr","zuhr","asr","magrib","isha"};
            Cursor allRows = myDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, resultColumns, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            Integer cindex = allRows.getColumnIndex("fajr");
            Integer cindex1 = allRows.getColumnIndex("zuhr");
            Integer cindex2 = allRows.getColumnIndex("asr");
            Integer cindex3 = allRows.getColumnIndex("magrib");
            Integer cindex4 = allRows.getColumnIndex("isha");
            allRows.moveToFirst();
            res1=allRows.getString(cindex);
            res2=allRows.getString(cindex1);
            res3=allRows.getString(cindex2);
            res4=allRows.getString(cindex3);
            res5=allRows.getString(cindex4);


            myDB.close();

            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            {
            try 
            {

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Rereive calender date
                hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // Take hour from the calender
                minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);    // Take minute from the calender
                minute1=minute + "";  // Convert minute to dtring
                if(minute1.equals("1")) 
                {
                minute1="01";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("2"))
                {
                minute1="02";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("3"))
                {
                minute1="03";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("4"))
                {
                minute1="04";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("5"))
                {
                minute1="05";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("6"))
                {
                minute1="06";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("7"))
                {
                minute1="07";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("8"))
                {
                minute1="08";
                }
                else if(minute1.equals("9"))
                {
                minute1="09";
                }
                     /* Converting to 12 hour format */
                if ( hour < 12 )
                {
                     hour=hour;
                     day3=hour + "" + ":" + minute1;
                     day4=day3 + " " + "AM"; // DAY4 Contains the system time
                }
                else
                {
                    hour=hour-12;
                    day3=hour + "" + ":" + minute1;
                    day4=day3 + " " + "PM";
                }



                if(day4.equals(res1))
              {
                     Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");


              }



                 if(day4.equals(res2))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }


                 if(day4.equals(res3))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  } 
                 if(day4.equals(res4))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }
                 if(day4.equals(res5))
                  {
                         Notification("Notification Title","Notification Message");

                  }

               Thread.sleep(1000);
       } 
       catch (InterruptedException e)
       {
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
               //System.out.println("New 1 Exception here");

       }

       catch (Exception e)
      {
               //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
           System.out.println("nEW Exception here");
      }          
       }

       }         
          @Override
          public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
          super.onStart(intent, startId);  
          Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
       }
         @Override
         public void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

         @Override
         public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
        }

         private  void Notification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage)
       {
         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

         Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         notification.setLatestEventInfo(MyService.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
         notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
   //HELLO_ID++;
         Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); 

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      try
      {
      mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);

      AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(
                                  Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      int volumen = audioManager.getStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

      if (volumen != 0) {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
      }
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {  
          System.out.println("Exception here");
          //System.out.println("Exception 1 here");
      }
      }
          }
```

Lgcat :

07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
07-27 16:24:52.591: E/global(363):  at org.prayer.test.splash$1.run(splash.java:71)
07-27 16:24:53.002: D/dalvikvm(363): GC freed 879 objects / 65552 bytes in 108ms
07-27 16:25:00.542: I/TestService(363): Service created...
07-27 16:25:20.752: I/dalvikvm(363): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-27 16:25:20.803: I/dalvikvm(363): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "forceclose".

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to trigger a notification at fixed times in a day, use AlarmManager to do this, as follows:

1. When application is started for first time, save those EditText values, etc as you are doing now - then set up AlarmManager to wake up your service at the nearest next notification time.
2. In the service, post the notification, set the next Alarm, and stopSelf().

This cycle will continue.

As for the force close, paste your logcat. Your code is not very neat, variables not meaningfully named, so its difficult to tell.

Comment: Aswin Kumar : My aim is to trigger the notifications with the time setted by the user.Not at fixed times.User will set the five prayer times simeltaneosly...I am trying to compare the time setted by the user with the devices time in a service...

Comment: You are saving the times to the db right? When triggering one notification, fetch the time for the next alarm, set it using AlarmManager.

Comment: Why cant I produce notifications in a background service?

Comment: You can, but its not optimal. Running a service with an infinite thread is pure waste of resources, when you can do it asynchronously using a system provided framework.

Comment: I am running the service with an infinite thread and the device is crashed.What was the reason for this?

Comment: Do you know how to view the logcat?

Comment: Aswin Kumar: I know how to schedule a notification at a specific time using alarm Manager.But I need to know how to set five notifications at five different times.

Comment: You have the time for the first alarm. Schedule the alarm manager to wake up your service at that time. Your service: 1) posts a notification with required content 2) queries your db and gets time for next notification 3) schedules alarm manager to wake up the service again at the new time 4) stops self

Comment: I attached the logcat above with the question

Comment: The log says "Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.", "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException ", "at java.lang.Thread.stop" . Obviously you are calling Thread.stop(), which is a deprecated api, and not supported on android.

Comment: I am checking my time comparison within  while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) loop in the service class..Then I call Thread.sleep(1000).Is there any problem on this infinite while loop...

Comment: I think Deprecated run time error occured on this while loop...Am I correct?

Comment: The exception is at line 71 in splash.java. Check what is happening there, or paste the splash.java here.

Comment: I think the exception on splash.java will not affect my notification.The remaining logcat errors are the reason for forceclosing

Comment: What about these logcat :   07-27 16:24:53.002: D/dalvikvm(363): GC freed 879 objects / 65552 bytes in 108ms 07-27 16:25:00.542: I/TestService(363): Service created... 07-27 16:25:20.752: I/dalvikvm(363): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3 07-27 ..16:25:20.803: I/dalvikvm(363): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'....